# how to centre bootsrap bottom navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

i have two navbars and i been trying to center the second navbars icons but its not working .When i aligned it left and right it works but once i do centre it doesnt work at all. Have i missed some part of code or made a mistake, therefore its not working. If anyone could help i would appreciate it.

thats the CSS code for my 2nd navbar:

```
.navbartwo {
overflow: hidden;

bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.navbartwo {
background-image: url(nav.png)
}


.navbartwo a {
float: centre;
display: inline-grid;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 13px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 15px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}



/* links on hover */
 .navbartwo a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
 }

 /*colour to the active/current link */
  .navbartwo a.active {
   color: #ebeef7;
    }


  .navbartwo.navbar-nav {
   display: inline-block;
   float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

   .navbartwo .navbar-collapse {
   text-align: center;
   }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="navbartwo">
<a href="#Dashboard">
    <svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-house-door" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z" />
    </svg>



    <a href="#Map"><svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-geo-alt" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M12.166 8.94c-.524 1.062-1.234 2.12-1.96 3.07A31.493 31.493 0 0 1 8 14.58a31.481 31.481 0 0 1-2.206-2.57c-.726-.95-1.436-2.008-1.96-3.07C3.304 7.867 3 6.862 3 6a5 5 0 0 1 10 0c0 .862-.305 1.867-.834 2.94zM8 16s6-5.686 6-10A6 6 0 0 0 2 6c0 4.314 6 10 6 10z" />
            <path d="M8 8a2 2 0 1 1 0-4 2 2 0 0 1 0 4zm0 1a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" />
        </svg></a>

    <a href="#Analysis"><svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-bar-chart-line" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M11 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7h1V2zm1 12h2V2h-2v12zm-3 0V7H7v7h2zm-5 0v-3H2v3h2z" />
        </svg></a>

    </svg></a>

<a href="#Community"><svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-people" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M15 14s1 0 1-1-1-4-5-4-5 3-5 4 1 1 1 1h8zm-7.978-1A.261.261 0 0 1 7 12.996c.001-.264.167-1.03.76-1.72C8.312 10.629 9.282 10 11 10c1.717 0 2.687.63 3.24 1.276.593.69.758 1.457.76 1.72l-.008.002a.274.274 0 0 1-.014.002H7.022zM11 7a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4zm3-2a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0zM6.936 9.28a5.88 5.88 0 0 0-1.23-.247A7.35 7.35 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4 0 .667.333 1 1 1h4.216A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.01.377-2.042 1.09-2.904.243-.294.526-.569.846-.816zM4.92 10A5.493 5.493 0 0 0 4 13H1c0-.26.164-1.03.76-1.724.545-.636 1.492-1.256 3.16-1.275zM1.5 5.5a3 3 0 1 1 6 0 3 3 0 0 1-6 0zm3-2a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4z" />
    </svg></a>
```

Comment: There is no such property/value as `float: centre;`

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/B6894R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have proceeded to put together this code snippet for you to review and use if this solves your issue. I would highly recommend to avoid using repetitive class rules in separate blocks, for example *.navbartwo* class being repeated several times,  I joined all of the rules and added some new in order to make this works.

**NOTE:** *You can remove the background color rule for the .navbartwo class. I placed it to visualize the icons since I don't have the current navbar background image at hand.*

I certainly hope this helps you with your request. Happy coding and keep up the good work, you are doing great so far!

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbartwo {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: between;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: url("nav.png")
}

.navbartwo a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}


/* links on hover */

.navbartwo a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}


/*colour to the active/current link */

.navbartwo a.active {
    color: #ebeef7;
}

.navbartwo.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbartwo .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"
         integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>DEMO FILE</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <main role="main" class="container">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbartwo">
               <a href="#Dashboard">
                  <svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-house-door" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z" />
                  </svg>
               <a href="#Map">
                  <svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-geo-alt" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M12.166 8.94c-.524 1.062-1.234 2.12-1.96 3.07A31.493 31.493 0 0 1 8 14.58a31.481 31.481 0 0 1-2.206-2.57c-.726-.95-1.436-2.008-1.96-3.07C3.304 7.867 3 6.862 3 6a5 5 0 0 1 10 0c0 .862-.305 1.867-.834 2.94zM8 16s6-5.686 6-10A6 6 0 0 0 2 6c0 4.314 6 10 6 10z" />
                     <path d="M8 8a2 2 0 1 1 0-4 2 2 0 0 1 0 4zm0 1a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" />
                  </svg>
               </a>
               <a href="#Analysis">
                  <svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-bar-chart-line" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M11 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7h1V2zm1 12h2V2h-2v12zm-3 0V7H7v7h2zm-5 0v-3H2v3h2z" />
                  </svg>
               </a>
               </svg></a>
               <a href="#Community">
                  <svg id="try" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="white" class="bi bi-people" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M15 14s1 0 1-1-1-4-5-4-5 3-5 4 1 1 1 1h8zm-7.978-1A.261.261 0 0 1 7 12.996c.001-.264.167-1.03.76-1.72C8.312 10.629 9.282 10 11 10c1.717 0 2.687.63 3.24 1.276.593.69.758 1.457.76 1.72l-.008.002a.274.274 0 0 1-.014.002H7.022zM11 7a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4zm3-2a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0zM6.936 9.28a5.88 5.88 0 0 0-1.23-.247A7.35 7.35 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4 0 .667.333 1 1 1h4.216A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.01.377-2.042 1.09-2.904.243-.294.526-.569.846-.816zM4.92 10A5.493 5.493 0 0 0 4 13H1c0-.26.164-1.03.76-1.724.545-.636 1.492-1.256 3.16-1.275zM1.5 5.5a3 3 0 1 1 6 0 3 3 0 0 1-6 0zm3-2a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4z" />
                  </svg>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
      <!-- /.container -->
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
         ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js
         "></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float: center doesn't exist, only float right or left.

If you want to center the 'a' tags on the center of the navbar, you can add to your navbartwo class this:

```
.navbartwo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Else if you want to just center the text of each 'a' tag add the same to the a tags like this:

```
.navbartwo a{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```